# Phonegap Sencha Show All Contacts

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, contacts

I want to show all my contacts using sencha touch and phonegap...i wrote the following code for that...but in Samsung Galaxy S3 it is taking more than 1 minute to load all the contacts(200 contacts). Any tips to make it faster

```
                        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
                        options.multiple=true;
                        var fields = ["displayName"];
                        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onDone, onError,options);
                        function onDone(contacts) {

                            Ext.getStore('strContacts').suspendEvents();
                            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                                var record = new Contacts.model.ContactsModel({
                                    givenName :contacts[i].displayName
                                });
                                Ext.getStore('strContacts').add(record);
                            }
                            Ext.getStore('strContacts').resumeEvents();
                            lst.unmask();

                        }
                        function onError(contactError) {
                            alert('onError!');
                            lst.unmask();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to write a native plugin which loads native contact picker. it is easily available for iOS but for android no one has published yet. that means you must learn plugin writing skill and do such native stuff.